# $G$ is Lie group and $V$ is a representations of $G$,prove representations $V \otimes V \cong S^2(V) \oplus \Lambda^2(V)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra, symmetric-algebra

Let $G$ a Lie group and let $V$ a representations of $G$. Then we have the following representations are isomorphic: 
\begin{align}
V \otimes V \cong S^2(V) \oplus  \Lambda^2(V)
\end{align}

I have no idea how to prove this fact. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about $v\otimes w\mapsto (v\otimes w + w\otimes v, v\otimes w - w\otimes v)$ ?

Comment: @Max It works, thank you!!